# Pass params to DRF API View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Is there a way to pass params to `serializer_class` in GenericAPIView?

As in, when I try to do

```
class SomeView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.SomeSerializer(fields=('a', 'b', 'c'))
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'SomeSerializer' object is not callable

I've also tried with the following:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    return serializers.SomeSerializer(
        fields=('a', 'b', 'c')
    )
```

instead of `serializer_class`, but the same error is triggered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Override the **`get_serializer_context(...)`** method

```
class SomeView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.SomeSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['fields'] = ('a', 'b', 'c')
        return context
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! As the fields I was looking at were of type `SerializerMethodField` I had to pass a flag through the context (in the way you suggested) and return empty lists if those flags were not there.